# how to send different form data to a php file for saving in database

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a lot of forms on different pages and I want to send these forms data to a single php file to store them in database.

E.g. for category, items, suppliers etc. I can't make php file for each to get and store its values in database from `$_POST` array...

That from each form or page calling the same php file for storing its data.
So I want to send a string like `INSERT INTO table() VALUES(txtfield_name, txtarea_description` etc. to the php file.

Comment: Are the forms all the same, or do they differ from eachother?

Comment: Can You please tell me which types of the form you are using for??
I think you are using different types of pages which are connected to the "previous" and "next" button right.

Comment: You have a project, not an isolated question.  Please spare the moderators and delete this question.  You need to write your own code.  (and no, don't send whole queries to the php file, that's a bad idea.)  Post only questions with isolated issues on SO.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a variable that you send along with the form to the php file and then in the php file you can set up a switch statement or nested if statements to identify the forms and then carry out operations on them.

```
<form action="page.php" method="post">
//set up a hidden variable that will help you identify the form
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="form1"/>
//then you can fill in other form inputs below
</form>
```

Then in your php file you obatain the form_id variable and check for the type

```
<?php

$form_id = $_POST['form_id'];

if($form_id == 'form1'){
   //carry out actions for form 1
 }
else if($form_id == 'form2'){
   //carry out actions for form 2
 }

//and so on for all your cases.
```

Let me know if it helps or in case you find a challenge

Comment: Yes, @Douglas Hosea you are right but in java we are making a single method for storing data e.g.
 `public void saveData(String sql) {
        try {
            connection();
            st = conn.createStatement();
            st.execute(sql);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your data has been saved...");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex, "Database error!", 1);
        }`

while the sql is a query sending from anywhere. Is that possible here in php.
but your logic is also fine. Thanks

Comment: Hey @NoorKhan, you might possibly be able to do where you just send an sql statement as a string to a function for database interactions but the problem comes with generating that sql string from the form data.  The only i can think of is placing the php code to generate the string in the same file as the forms with an isset function to check if the form_submit button is the one clicked so as to execute the code or do nothing. Although that is a longer process but it is doable, just a problem of how to generate the sql string.